# Podcast cover art missing since upgrading to iOS 5

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, podcasts

Since upgrading my iPhone 3GS to iOS 5 some of my podcasts no longer display their custom cover art. They sync OK but use the default image. I'm still syncing over USB, no iCloud or Wi-Fi sync at the moment. The cover art displays correctly in iTunes itself.

- How can I get the missing cover art back on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this myself in the end by deleting the podcasts on the iPhone itself and then re-syncing. Sometimes it took several attempts before the cover art came back.

Comment: The artwork database is apart from the music, so this has more to do with a sync error than iOS 5. Any restore / update can do for the event to expose a database error and break the sync between song and art.